# Output of the logit function as addtional input to a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, heuristics

This is w.r.t a hybrid of ANN and logistic regression in a binary classification problem. For example in one of the papers I came across they state that "A hybrid  model type  is  constructed  by  using  the  logistic  regression  model  to  calculate  the  probability  of  failure and then adding that value as an additional input variable into the ANN.  This type of model is defined as a Plogit-ANN model".

So, for n input variables, I'm trying to understand how the additional input n+1 to a ANN is treated by the activation function (eg. a logit function) and in the summation of weights multiplied by inputs. Do we treat this probability variable n+1 as one of the standalone weights like a special type of b0 that we add in the sum of weights multiplied by inputs e.g. Summation for each Neuron = (Sum (Wi*Xi))+additional variable.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description provided the easiest way is to treat this as **additional feature** of your data. So you have a model that predicts something about your original dataset (probability of some additional thing), thus you get x -> f(x). You simply concatenate it to your feature vector so x' = [x1 x2 ... xk f(x)], and push it through the network.

However the described approach is quite naive, since you are doing these two things (training f and training neural net) completely independently), what might be more beneficial is to instead treat fitting f as an auxiliary loss and train your model jointly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You've clarified my confusion about the relevance of f(x) as input. May you please explain further on this point "treat fitting f as an auxiliary loss and train your model jointly.". I'm not following what you meant.